# Enter the short link in the browser bar and redirect to the main Url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to enter a short link of a site in the browser bar as follows:
localhost:0000/a.

And after pressing the next key, I will go to the site related to the short link. Short links and main links are stored in the SQL database with this code.

Can you help me?

```
public void GetLinkByShortLink(string shortlink)
{
    DB_LinksEntities db = new DB_LinksEntities();

    var result = (from a in db.Tbl_Links
                  where a.ShortLink==shortlink
                  select new { a.Link }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `Redirect` to your `main` link as follows:

```
public string GetLinkByShortLink(string shortlink){

    DB_LinksEntities db = new DB_LinksEntities();

    var result = (from a in db.Tbl_Links
              where a.ShortLink==shortlink
              select new { a.Link }).FirstOrDefault();}
```

So you can write your `Action` in your `Controller` as follows:

```
 public ActionResult SomeAction(string shortLink)
 {
        var link=GetLinkByShortLink(shortLink);
        if(link!=null){
          return Redirect(link)
        }
        return NotFound();
 }
```